# Retrieve all Discord Channel IDs with matching names

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm using NodeJS, and trying to create a bot with DiscordJS that finds all channels named the same, and send a message to each one.

```
const PREFIX = "<";
const { Client, DiscordAPIError }= require('discord.js');
const { findSourceMap } = require('module');
const disclient = new Client();
require('dotenv').config();
disclient.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);

disclient.on('ready',() => {
    console.log('Discord logged on');
});
disclient.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)){
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
        .trim()
        .substring(PREFIX.length)
        .split(/\s+/);
        
        let channels = message.guild.channels.cache;
        if (CMD_NAME === "findchannel"){
            
         let clamnewschan =  disclient.channels.cache.find(channels => channels.name === "clamnews");
         
        };
    };
});
```

I have no idea how to do this, but I have managed to get the channel with the name "clamnews", I just need its ID so I can post into it.

EDIT: Fixed, updated code down below.

```
const PREFIX = "<";
const { Client, DiscordAPIError }= require('discord.js');
const { findSourceMap } = require('module');
const disclient = new Client();
require('dotenv').config();
disclient.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);

disclient.on('ready',() => {
    console.log('Discord logged on');
});
disclient.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)){
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
        .trim()
        .substring(PREFIX.length)
        .split(/\s+/);
        
        let channels = disclient.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.name === "clamnews");
        if (CMD_NAME === "findchannel"){
            
        channels.forEach(channel => channel.send("test"))
         
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to find the channels that have the same name and post into them you could do it like that:

```js
let channels = disclient.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.name === "clamnews");
channels.forEach(channel => channel.send("test"))
```

This example filters out every channel that is named `clamnews`. This is stored in `channels`. Then you simply use the `forEach` function to send the message to every channel with the same name.

Comment: This works, but for only the guild I send the test command into. Is there a way to make it so this works for multiple guilds?